# Hover on span inside div, show other element

Tags: css, hover

I wanted the div id='cancelReq' to be displayed when the mouse hover at span id='requestSent'

I've tried this code, but it's not working.

```
<style> 
    #cancelReq {
         display: none;
    }

    #requestSent:hover + #cancelReq { 
         display: block;
    }   
</style>

<div id='addUser'>
     <span id='requestSent'>Add Friend</span>
</div>
<div id='cancelReq' >hello there</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript for that.
Here is the code for your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function fun(){
         document.getElementById("cancelReq").style.display = "block";
     }

     function fun1(){
         document.getElementById("cancelReq").style.display = "none";
     }
</script>
```

And make your HTML code like following:

```
<div id='addUser'><span id='requestSent' onmouseover="fun();" onmouseout="fun1();" >Add Friend</span></div>
<div id='cancelReq' >hello there</div>
```